# how to tell yoxos that my update site has changed

Tags: eclipse, p2, yoxos

I have a private yoxos profile with the yoxos launcher (5.6 CI20130625-0201) have added a private update pages.

For some reasons yoxos does not load the newest version form the update site. It alwyas
uses an old version. However, if I enable the update interface and enter the update site, then eclipse will offer me to update to the newest version. However yoxos always installs the old version.

Here is what I have tried without success:

- remove the plugin via the web interface and reinstall it
- remove the update site via the web interface and add it again

What I have not tried is to create a new update site But that is a bit annoying to create a new update site for every minor version I want to install.

What is the trick to tell yoxos to flush its caches?

Comment: Now I have tried to create a new update site with a new URL and that works:
1. remove the out-dated update site
2. add the new update site
3. add the features again.

Comment: If you have found an answer to your question, you should post it as answer. Answering your own questions is explicitly allowed on stackoverflow.

Comment: I will add the answer -- so far the only way I found out is to create new update sites when the extension has changed -- but that is only an option if you have control over the update site :-(

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: until someone finds a better answer, this is the best I can come up with:

The only (very annoying way) to solve this (that I have figured out) is to create a new update site for a new release:

1. remove the out-dated update site
2. add the new update site
3. add the features again

This is **very bad** but it seems to be the only way to get it working.